# How Can i get Two column winform listbox in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am doing Student Attendance project for college in win form with MySQL(C#).

In that I want to move data one listbox to another listbox. I done that. But i load the student name in that. Now Client Want Name and adminno like datagridview Columns.

I search for this,. Vb has this type of coding. See [Multi Column Listbox](http://www.dicks-blog.com/archives/2004/05/24/sorting-a-multicolumn-listbox/). Is it Possible in C#?.

[image]

See the Below Picture. Its my Form.,..

[image]

**My Code For Loading Listbox**

```
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
        MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
        MySqlDataReader Reader;
        command.CommandText = "select name,admin_no from student_admision_master where course='" + course_code + "' AND year='" + year_code + "' AND sem='" + semester_code + "' AND batch='" + batch_code + "'";
        connection.Open();
        Reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (Reader.Read())
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(Reader[0].ToString() + "," + Reader[1].ToString());
        }
        connection.Close();
```

This give the result jagadees, 125445.
But want to disparate Separate Columns.

**My Code For Moving Data's**

```
private void btn_toAb_Click_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int count = listBox1.Items.Count;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        listBox2.Items.Add(listBox1.Items[i].ToString());
    }
    listBox1.Items.Clear();
}

private void btn_fromAb_Click_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int count = listBox2.Items.Count;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(listBox2.Items[i].ToString());
    }
    listBox2.Items.Clear();
}

private void btn_toAb_Selected_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int count = listBox1.SelectedItems.Count;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        listBox2.Items.Add(listBox1.SelectedItems[i].ToString());
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItems[0]);
        //listBox1.add

    }
}

private void btn_fromAb_Selected_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int count = listBox2.SelectedItems.Count;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(listBox2.SelectedItems[i].ToString());
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        listBox2.Items.Remove(listBox2.SelectedItems[0]);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Windows Forms Control "ListView" can do that.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by using String.Format() method. Inside is each method yoz define the alignment of each item in a row.
I dont have a db, but instead in my example I use two array (same as your reader[0] and reader[1] indexers). So Instead of array1[i], and array2[i] you use Reader[0] and Reader[1].
Here is the exampe:

```
        string[] array1 = { "name 1", "name10", "name104", "name 222", "name 3212" };
        string[] array2 = { "12343", "23", "432", "4333", "1" };

        const int a = 40;
        int b = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++)
        {
            if (array1[i].Contains(' '))
                b = array1[i].Length - 1;
            else
                b = array1[i].Length;
            b = -(a - b);
            listBox1.Items.Add(String.Format("{0," + b + "} {1}", array1[i], array2[i]));
        }
```